# How to prevent gulp-livereload from binding to IPv6 listening port

Tags: ipv6

I'm using gulp-sass and gulp-livereload as part of my tool chain for web development. This is working nicely on my MacBook Pro, but trying to run gulp-livereload on Ubuntu 14.04 is resulting in it binding only to an IPv6 port, which doesn't help me when Apache is bound to IPv4. Consequently, the Chrome livereload extension is failing to connect.

How can I prevent gulp-livereload on the server side trying to use the IPv6 protocol (or else bind to ports for both IP versions)?

I tried disabling IPv6 altogether (using instructions [here](https://support.purevpn.com/how-to-disable-ipv6-linuxubuntu)), but this made no difference according to netstat - various processes including gulp are still showing up as tcp6 in netstat.

Comment: Start by fixing your Apache configuration so that it is also listening on IPv6.

Comment: It is actually (after re-enabling IPv6). Chrome is connecting via IPv4 though, and gulp stubbornly chooses to only use IPv6.

Comment: Same issue also observed on new Ubuntu 16.04 system with fairly generic LAMP stack.

Comment: What protocols a process binds to has little-to-no impact on what protocol it uses to establish a connection.

Comment: I have to disagree with that statement. A process listening on a TCPv6 port is not going to accept (or even be notified of) an incoming TCPv4 connection request. Perhaps you misunderstood my question.

Comment: @JohnRix A socket listening on `::` can receive IPv4 connections as well. That's what `::ffff:0.0.0.0/96` is for.

Comment: Thanks kasperd, I was not aware of that. In that case, I'm not sure where the problem is with livereload, as connections are failing regardless. Might have to break out a packet sniffer.